# Debugging Kubebuilder tests

Tags: go, goland, kubernetes-go-client, kubebuilder

Is there a way to debug the tests while developing a Kubernetes Operator (using the Kubebuilder framework)?

For instance, I have the following files with the same package `controller`:

- internal/controller/component_a.go
- internal/controller/component_b.go
- and other files up till component_f.go

And then, as usual, I have the `suite_test.go` & `component_test.go` files in the same directory as the components (with the same package name `controller`).

Running `make test` works perfectly fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to attach a debugger and add breakpoints somehow.

I've currently tried a couple of ways to attach a debugger:

- Tried replicating the exact same configuration in GoLand:

  - Added a run configuration with a *Before Launch* configuration to execute a Shell script with (Script Text selected) and the contents as the contents of the `make` targets `manifests generate fmt vet envtest` (which are run automatically when we run `make test`). Didn't work, since the shell script execution runs in one window, and then the `go test` execution runs in a fresh window inside GoLand. Ends up not being able to even start the control plane since the `make envtest` is crucial to set up the envtest binaries.
  - Added a run configuration with *Before Launch* configuration as *Make targets*. Didn't work. Complains about the same as above.
  - Tried running the `make test` in the terminal, and then running `Attach to process` inside GoLand, to attach to the go process of `go test ./...`. But that fails with an error:

    ```
    could not attach to pid 84628: stub exited while waiting for connection: exit status 0
    ```

    Meanwhile, attaching to other processes (like `kube-apiserver` and `etcd`) works like a charm, but I have no use attaching to them :).
- Tried to run the tests via `dlv test`:

  - Tried running `dlv test ./... -output /dev/null` but that fails with:

    ```
    could not launch process: not an executable file
    could not remove /dev/null: remove /dev/null: operation not permitted
    ```

I'm happy to share any more details.

Any ideas as to how I can debug this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this guide: https://auscunningham.medium.com/debug-kubernetes-operator-sdk-locally-in-goland-27b7909c417a?